# Lignhing Components Rendering - end of carreer issue

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps

It is a complex issue so I'll try to descrive each steap as clearly as possible.

At first I hace this CMP that I 'll call "rootCMP".

*EDIT:*

> This component is called from an event because it works as a right
>   side bar and need to render it with parameters that comes from other
>   components on the page. For this case parameter1 value comes with this event.

***RootCMP***

```
<aura:component controller="OController">
  <aura:attribute name="parameter1" type="String" />

  <div class="ASH2 slds-border_bottom" > TITLEt </div>
    <div class="H1" /> 
  <div>
      <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="slds-text-heading_small slds-p-bottom_small">
      SUBTITLE1
    </div>

    <c:CMP_ListigItems parameter1="{!v.parameter1}"/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="slds-text-heading_small slds-p-bottom_medium">
      SUBTITLE2
    </div>
    <c:CMP_Parent1 parameter1="{!v.parameter1}"/>
  </div>
/aura:component>
```

This ***RootCMP*** calls to ***CMP_ListingItems*** who receives parameter1 from ***RootCMP***

```
<aura:component>
  <aura:attribute name="label" type="String" />
  <aura:attribute name="itemsList" type="Items__c[]" />
  <aura:attribute name="parameter1" type="String" default=""/>

  <c:AS_GetItemsByParametery parameter1="{!v.parameter1}" items="{!v.itemsList}"/>

  <div class="slds-pill_container">
    <aura:iteration var="item" items="{!v.itemsList}">
      <c:AS_ITemPill item="{!item}" parameter1="{!v.parameter1}" />
    </aura:iteration>
  </div>
</aura:component>
```

The component ***AS_GetItemsByParameter*** is used to retrieve a list of items filtered by parameter1.

***AS_GetItemsByParameter***

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,force:lightningQuickAction" controller="Controller" access="global">
parameter1 | {!v.strategyId}
  <aura:attribute name="parameter1" type="String" />
  <aura:attribute name="items" type="Item__c[]" />

  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onInit}" />
</aura:component>
```

As you can see in this CMP i'm printing the value of ***parameter1*** and it is being showed in the screen. The issue starts in the controller.

***AS_GetItemsByParameterController.js***
in the third line of the onInit method, you can see an alert to view the value of parameted1 but the value that it throws is ***undefined***

```
({
  onInit: function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.getITemsByParameter");
    var parameter1 = component.get("v.parameter1");
    alert(JSON.stringify(parameter1));
    action.setParams({
      parameter1: parameter1
    });

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
      var state = response.getState();
      if (state === "SUCCESS") {
        var items = response.getReturnValue();
        component.set("v.items", items);
      } else {
        console.log("Failed with state: " + state);
      }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
  },

});
```

Assumptions:

- The apex code who is called by the controller is working well for other methods.
- The architecture of usng a component to retrieve things and other to list them is working in other components too.

Comment: can you please update u r question with how did you get `v.parameter1` value in `RootCMP`?

Comment: @sdandamud1 done! thanks for your time on reading my question.

Comment: can add aura if for testing to check parameter1 is exiting while loading childcmp  ` <aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.parameter1))}"> <c:CMP_ListigItems parameter1="{!v.parameter1}"/> </aura:if> `

Comment: @sdandamud1 I just tested your Idea, but the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

The issue  was the event who builds ***RootCMP***

I was building it using just an aura:if and solved it loading dynamically de RootComponent.

In the solution I replaced the aura:if with an attribute of type Component.

and it is being loaded with a function like this:

```
loadRootCMP: function(component) {
        $A.createComponent("c:RootCMP", 
        {
            "parameter1"  : component.get("v.parameter1"),
        }, 
        function(newCmp, status, errorMessage) {
            if (component.isValid()) {
                if(status == "ERROR") {
                    console.log('Creating Dynnamic component- Error Message--',errorMessage);
                }
                component.set("v.RootCMPContainer", newCmp);
            } 
        } );
  },
```